# Problema con la ejecución de código AJAX después de recibir una respuesta exitosa desde PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, fetch

Estoy experimentando dificultades al intentar ejecutar código AJAX después de recibir una respuesta exitosa desde PHP.

Tengo un formulario de inicio de sesión en mi página web y estoy utilizando AJAX para enviar los datos del formulario al servidor y recibir una respuesta en formato JSON desde mi PHP. El objetivo es redirigir al usuario a una página específica si el inicio de sesión es exitoso.

Aquí está mi código AJAX actual:

```
// Obtener una referencia al formulario y al botón de enviar
var form = document.getElementById('loginForm');
var submitButton = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');

// Agregar un controlador de eventos al botón de enviar
submitButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Evitar que el formulario se envíe de forma tradicional

    // Obtener los datos del formulario
    var formData = new FormData(form);

    // Realizar la solicitud fetch
    fetch('login.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams(formData)
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.ok) {
                // La solicitud se completó exitosamente
                return response.json();
            } else {
                // Hubo un error en la solicitud
                throw new Error('Error: ' + response.status);
            }
        })
        .then(function (data) {
            if (data.success === true) {
                alert(data.message);

                // Realizar la redirección al obtener una respuesta exitosa
                window.location.href = 'tests.html';
            } else {
                // Mostrar mensaje de error
                alert(data.message);
            }
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // Manejar errores de la solicitud
            console.error(error);
        });
});
```

El problema es que el código dentro del bloque then que maneja una respuesta exitosa, específicamente la redirección window.location.href, no se ejecuta correctamente. No se produce ninguna redirección a la página "tests.html", a pesar de que la respuesta del servidor indica un inicio de sesión exitoso.

El código de mi PHP que envía la respuesta es este:

```
if ($hashedPassword === $user_password) {
        // La contraseña es correcta, permite el acceso del usuario
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

       
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        setcookie("sesion", true, time() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60, '/', ''); // Configurar la cookie de sesión
        echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Inicio de sesion exitoso'));
        
    } else {
        error_log("Acceso denegado");
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Acceso denegado'));
    }
```

He verificado que la respuesta del servidor sea correcta y contiene la propiedad success con el valor true. Sin embargo, el código dentro del bloque then simplemente no se ejecuta.

¿Existe alguna razón o error común por el cual el código dentro del bloque then no se ejecutaría después de recibir una respuesta exitosa desde PHP? ¿Hay alguna solución o enfoque alternativo recomendado para lograr la redirección después de recibir una respuesta exitosa?

Agradezco cualquier sugerencia o orientación que puedan proporcionar. ¡Muchas gracias!

***Ampliación del código PHP:***

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://tests.allesconsultores.com.ar');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');

session_start();

// Conexión a la base de datos
$servername = "*******";
$username = "********";
$db_password = "********";
$dbname = "****";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $db_password, $dbname);

// Comprobar la conexión
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    error_log("Conexión fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
    die("Conexión fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Recibir datos del formulario
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
if (isset($_POST['remember']) && $_POST['remember'] == 'on') {
    // Establece la cookie "remember" con un tiempo de expiración, por ejemplo, 10 días
    setcookie('remember', '1', time() + (10 * 24 * 60 * 60), '/', '');
}

$_SESSION["email"] = $email;

// Preparar la consulta SQL utilizando sentencias preparadas
$sql = "SELECT password, salt FROM users WHERE email=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $user_password = $row["password"];
    $salt = $row["salt"];

    // Realizar el salting concatenando la contraseña proporcionada con la sal almacenada en la base de datos
    $saltedPassword = $password . $salt;

    // Realizar key stretching mediante iteraciones para verificar la contraseña
    $hashedPassword = hashPassword($saltedPassword);

    // Verificar la contraseña proporcionada
    if ($hashedPassword === $user_password) {
       // La contraseña es correcta, permite el acceso del usuario
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

        setcookie("sesion", true, time() + 1 * 24 * 60 * 60, '/', ''); // Configurar la cookie de sesión
        
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array('success' => true, 'message' => 'Inicio de sesion exitoso'));
    } else {
        error_log("Acceso denegado");
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Acceso denegado'));
    }
} else {
    error_log("Usuario no encontrado");
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode(array('success' => false, 'message' => 'Usuario no encontrado'));
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

function hashPassword($password)
{
    // Realiza el key stretching mediante iteraciones para aumentar la seguridad
    $iterations = 10000; // Puedes ajustar este valor según tus necesidades
    $hashedPassword = $password;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $iterations; $i++) {
        $hashedPassword = hash('sha256', $hashedPassword);
    }

    return $hashedPassword;
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Pero ves el `alert` que dice: *`Inicio de sesion exitoso`*? ¿El archivo `tests.html` existe en la ruta de tu script actual? ¿Has probado con la ruta absoluta de `tests.html`?

Comment: No, el alert no se muestra. Directamente recarga la pagina y no me lleva a ningún lado. El archivo sí existe y la ruta es la indicada.

Comment: ¿Y si comentas esta línea temporalmente `//window.location.href = 'tests.html';` el `alert` sí se muestra? ¿Ningún error en consola?

Comment: No, no se muestra, incluso comentando la linea. Se refresca la página y se vacían los campos.

Comment: Pues algo pasa en tu php. ¿No tienes más cosas en él?

Comment: Sí, pero lo he depurado y resulta que se ejecuta correctamente. Ya lo agrego

Comment: Me confunde que dices haber verificado la respuesta del servidor y que es correcta..¿Dónde la verificaste?

Comment: La he verificado mediante Sandbox de PHP

Comment: Al parecer en Fetch si trabajas con session y cookies, debes indicarlo explícitamente en la petición, prueba a agregar `credentials: 'same-origin'` a tu petición. [Revisa la doc para más detalles](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#enviar_una_petición_con_credenciales_incluido).

Comment: No, lamentablemente no es ese el problema. No puedo dar con la respuesta y he investigado mucho, pero no la encuentro

Comment: Creo que tratas de ir muy rápido. Afirmas que la respuesta del script PHP es exitosa porque lo has probado en otro entorno, pero no tienes forma de comprobar que es exitosa desde el browser, y parece no serlo. Al código le falta un `.catch`. Dónde dice el comentario `// Manejar errores de la solicitud` en realidad estás manejando errores del parser de JSON, pero no hay un `.catch` para manejar los posibles errores de la solicitud. Y es que ya vas por la segunda promesa (la del parser) sin haber verificado que el `.fetch` funcione.

Comment: Sugiero que vayas más despacio, haz solo el `fetch` con su `then/catch`. Tan sencillo como un alert para ver el contenido devuelto llevar a consola los status y mensajes de error. Cuando ya todo esté bien a ese nivel, metes la segunda promesa, invocando al parser de JSON con su nuevo then y catch, igual ver el resultado en consola o en alertas y cuando ya todo OK, entonces haces la redirección. A mi, me suena a depuración básica durante el desarrollo, sobre todo si estás intentando usar cosas nuevas para ti.

Comment: A mi me late que el error esta en otro lado, dices que la pagina se te recarga, pero el fetch nada tiene que ver con esa recarga, por lo que deduzco que algo esta causando que tu funcion click no se ejecute correctamente, ignorando el e.preventDefault y haciendo que el formulario termine haciendo un get si mismo (y por lo tanto generando la recarga de la pagina)

Comment: No ves ningún otro error en la consola de Javascript?

Comment: No, en la consola no aparece ningun error relacionado

Comment: Puede ser que la solución sea sacar el botón del form, el preventDefault en el botón no evita que el formulario haga lo suyo, mejor cuando caiga el click  envías con form.submit().